# Evaluating six conditions efficently and clearly

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, validation, nested-loops

I have the following (simplified) conditions that need to be validated for a form I am writing:

a > b

a > c

a > d

b > c

b > d

c > d

Graphically, this can be seen as:

[image]

The user has freedom to enter values for a, b, c, and d, which is why they need to be validated to make sure they obey those rules.  The problem I am having is writing something that clearly and efficiently evaluates each statement.  Of course, the most obvious way would be to evaluate each statement separately as an if-statement.  Unfortunately, this takes up a lot of lines of code, and I'd rather avoid cluttering up the method with a bunch of if-blocks that do almost the same thing.  I did come up with the following nested for-loop solution, using arrays.  I built an array of the values, and looped over it twice (demonstrated in Python-like pseudo-code):

```
A = [a, b, c, d]
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(i, 4):
        if i > j and A[i] >= A[j]:
            print("A[i] must be less than A[j]")
        else if i < j and A[i] <= A[j]:
            print("A[j] must be greater than A[i]")
```

The problem I have with this solution is it is hard to read and understand - the solution just isn't clear.

I have this nagging feeling that there is a better, clearer answer out there, but I can't think of it for the life of me.  This isn't homework or anything - I am actually working on a project and this problem (or subtle variations of it) arose more than once, so I would like to make a reusable solution that is clear and efficient.  Any input would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the requirement is that `A` is sorted in descending order with no duplicate elements.

Comment: instead of telling the user they entered the values in the wrong order, could you just silently sort them so that they _are_ in the correct order? Or are the values not interchangeable in that way?

Comment: In my particular problem, there isn't a real order.  You have basically four boxes, a b c and d, and you should know the rules I listed above.  If your input is invalid, I would like to message the user telling them what they should change, exactly.  That means listing all failed cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if a > b > c > d:
    do ok
else:
    for x in range(3):
        if A[i] <= A[i+1]:
             print A[i], ' not greater than', A[i+1]
```

Comment: Checking each cell with the cell after that is not enough, look at this example: `[4, 3, 2, 4]`, Your code will only print `2 should be grater than 4` but it's not enough.

Comment: It's enough to know the data is faulty.

Comment: `3 should be grater than 4` is also a faulty data.

Comment: MostafaR is correct here.  I want all bad cases to be printed, not just one (even though one may be sufficient for our purposes).

Answer (score 2):

If you can't assume transitivity of comparison:

```
from itertools import combinations
for x, y in combinations(A, 2):
    if x <= y:
        print("{} not greater than {}".format(x, y))
```

Otherwise, f p's solution is optimal.

Comment: Thanks, but I actually am not writing in Python (C# to be precise).  I just used a Python-like pseudocode to clearly present the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could create delegates for each check and add these to an array. Create appropriate delegates, like bool LargerCheck(a,b, string error) and add them to an array which you can loop through...

A lot of work though and more complex, if more readable. I think I would just hide the messy checks in a single validationblock and have a easily readable single check in the normal code. Something like this;

```
// Simple readable check in normal code
if (!ValidationOk(a,b,c,d,response) 
{
  ShowResponse(response);
  Break;
}


// messy routine
private bool ValidationOk(a,b,c,d,List<string> valerrors)
{
  valerrors.Clear();
  if (a<b) valerrors.Add("a < b");
  if (a<c) valerrors.Add("a < c");
  ....
  return valerrors.Count == 0;
}
```